# Python module can't be found in DoHlyzer tool

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

I'm trying to use the [DoHlyzer tool](https://github.com/ahlashkari/DoHlyzer). When I launch `dohlyzer.py` which is in the meter folder I got the error

> ```
> File "dohlyzer.py", line 8, in <module>  
>     from meter.flow_session import generate_session_class  
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'meter'
> ```

Although the folder meter have the `flow_session.py` file.

Comment: Did you executed `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: yes, I executed it

Comment: is this the whole stack trace of the error?

Comment: @Henil yes, it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that this code is not properly built, as it considers itself being installed as a module, without providing a proper setup.py/pyproject.toml file to make it installable.

So as a quick'n dirty way to make it work you can add a sample `setup.py` file so that you can install the tool:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="dohlyzer",
    description="Set of tools to capture HTTPS traffic, extract statistical and time-series features from it, and analyze them with a focus on detecting and characterizing DoH (DNS-over-HTTPS) traffic.  ",
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/ahlashkari/DoHlyzer",
    packages=find_packages(exclude=[]),
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    install_requires=open('requirements.txt').read().split('\n'),
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "dohlyzer=meter.dohlyzer:main",
        ]
    },
)
```

To test that you can use a virtualenv:

```
% virtualenv venv
% venv/bin/pip install .
% venv/bin/dohlyzer -h
usage: dohlyzer [-h] (-n INPUT_INTERFACE | -f INPUT_FILE) (-c | -s) output

positional arguments:
  output                output file name (in flow mode) or directory (in sequence mode)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -n INPUT_INTERFACE, --online INPUT_INTERFACE, --interface INPUT_INTERFACE
                        capture online data from INPUT_INTERFACE
  -f INPUT_FILE, --offline INPUT_FILE, --file INPUT_FILE
                        capture offline data from INPUT_FILE
  -c, --csv, --flow     output flows as csv
  -s, --json, --sequence
                        output flow segments as json
```

or you can install it globally:

```
% pip install .
```

N.B.: that setup.py file has several issues and is only good for a quick hack, if you want to make it clean, I suggest you to read [some documentation about it](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)

Comment: indeed, there's no way to cheat: make it a package and all will be ok 

Comment: also you should report that as a bug, it's obviously a forgotten file from them and/or write one and submit it to them as a pull-request